# Word done is giving me syntax error ocaml?

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

im trying to do a while do done loop in ocaml, but im having a syntax error on the line 21 (the line that just says done) and i dont know whats the error.

```
let ver = 1 in
while ver > 0  do 
let () = Printf.printf "Olá, insere o número de casas que o tabuleiro tem numa linha, separe por um espaço\n" in
let tudo = read_line () in (* Le a linha inserida*)
let ncc = tudo.[0] in (*ncc = Numero de Casas Char*)
let ncs = Char.escaped ncc in (*ncs = Numero de Casas String*)
let nc = int_of_string ncs in (* passa a string para int para termos o numero de casas em int para podermos trabalhar*)
let () = Printf.printf "%d" nc in
let pcc = tudo.[2] in
let pcs = Char.escaped pcc in
let pc = int_of_string pcs in
let () = Printf.printf "%d" pc in
let a1c = tudo.[4] in
let a1s = Char.escaped a1c in
let a1 = int_of_string a1s in
let () = Printf.printf "%d" a1 in
let b1c = tudo.[6] in
let b1s = Char.escaped b1c in
let b1 = int_of_string b1s in
let ver = if (nc < 51 && nc > 0 && pc < 9 && pc > 0  ) then 0 else  1 in
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Your last line before `done` calculates a value for `ver` but then doesn't do anything with it. It doesn't make sense for an expression to end with `in`.

Possibly you're missing an expression after `in`. Otherwise it's not clear why you're calculating `ver`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code mainly stems from your understanding of what `let ... in` does.

When you type `let x = ... in expr`, you create a **new** variable `x` that will apply in your expression `expr` and only there. That means your two declarations of `ver`:

```
let ver = 1 in
...
let ver = if (nc < 51 && nc > 0 && pc < 9 && pc > 0  ) then 0 else  1 in
```

Those declare two different variables `ver` and only the first one is used in the condition to your `while` loop (which will be an infinite loop as a result).

Now, to your syntax error.

As Jeffrey pointed out, `done` indicates the end of a loop. It is not an expression but more like a closing parentheses. However, `let ... in` expects an expression to follow it (where your variable will "exist"). This is not what you want, since you want the new value of `ver` to escape its scope.

#### The quick and dirty solution

You can declare `ver` to be a reference. That is "a value you can mutate" in OCaml (by default, all values declared are constants). You declare a new reference with `ref`, assign it with `:=` and read it with `!`. Example:

```
let ver = ref true in (* I switched to a boolean, you can easily go back to integer *)
while !ver do
 (* ... *)
 let b1 = int_of_string b1s in
 ver := not (nc < 51 && nc > 0 && pc < 9 && pc > 0  )
done
```

Note that this is not how an OCaml dev would usually code this, as we prefer to keep our variables immutable and loop using a recursive function.

#### The OCaml way

Recursive functions allow to do what any `while` loop does while at the same time giving you syntactic control over what is mutable or not.

```
let rec loop () =
 (* ... *)
 let b1 = int_of_string b1s in
 if (nc < 51 && nc > 0 && pc < 9 && pc > 0  ) then () else loop ()
in loop ()
```

Note that there is no `ver` variable here, as the loop directly calls itself back when needed. If you are trying to calculate something, you can easily return the result in the `then` clause. Note that in my codes (and yours), no variable escapes the loop by default.